# Max flow algorithm - Ford-Fulkerson's method

Tags: algorithm, methods, graph, bipartite

I know I shouldn't ask this sort of question, but I'm hopeless atm, I need some help...

I got this question for my assignment - there is a broad that has m by n grid of squares, and we are trying to cut the grid by two adjacent squares - either vertically or horizontally. However, some squares in the board cant be used as they are defective. so what's the maximum number of pieces we can cut?

I was thinking using Ford-Fulkerson's method - that converts each square into vertex, but cant really figure out what should I do next...

Can some one comes up with a hint?

Many Thanks

Comment: please review: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cut the grid by two adjacent squares"? also, on the surface it looks like a max matching rather than max flow problem